# R: Remove punctuations except squared brackets "[" "]" and question mark "?"

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to remove all punctuations from my data except for "?" "[" and "]". I was only able to do this for "?", where I have done the following:

```
gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]?\"]", "", data)
```

However, what do I need to do in order to include "[" and "]" too?

For example, let's presume that the data input is:

- Oh nooo!!! I don't like lemons [sad]
- What do you think about it?

I want the output to look like this

- Oh nooo I dont like lemons [sad]
- What do you think about it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe something like `gsub("[^\\[\\]\\?[:^punct:]]", "", x, perl = TRUE)`?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 perfect :) it worked! thank  youuuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have "x" as:

```
x <- c("Oh nooo!!! I don't like lemons [sad]", "What do [you] think about it?!")
```

you can try:

```
gsub("[^\\[\\]\\?[:^punct:]]", "", x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "Oh nooo I dont like lemons [sad]" "What do [you] think about it?"
```